# How to call model in controller on constructor because I need write only one time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a model for fetching data then write code

model..

```
 function get_courses(){
        $this->db->from(TABLE_COURSE);
        $this->db->where('name !=', '');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = '';
        if($query){
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
                $result = $query->result();
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Controller

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Quiz extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Mastermodel','',TRUE);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['courses'] = $this->Mastermodel->get_courses();
        $data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_list";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $data);
    }
    public function quiz_of_day()
    {
        $data['courses'] = $this->Mastermodel->get_courses();
        $data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_of_day";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $data);
    }
    public function quiz_edit()
    {
        $data['courses'] = $this->Mastermodel->get_courses();
        $data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_edit";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $data);
    }
}
```

How to call model in controller on constructor because I need write only one time?

Comment: i think you have already set the databse setting in database.php file try to load model like this $this->load->model('Mastermodel'); i will work

Comment: your question is still not clear, here you called your `get_courses()` model function in three diff controller function, Do you want single call which will allow you to use three time?

Comment: @umefarooq Yes i Already set the database setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you can do the following...

1. You need to make the $data array a property of the class
2. Reference the new $this->data throughout the class
3. You need to move your call to the model in the constructor.

So what you get is this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Quiz extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = array(); // Old school definition of an array (instead of [])for safety

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Mastermodel', '', TRUE);

        $this->data['courses'] = $this->Mastermodel->get_courses();
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_list";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $this->data);
    }

    public function quiz_of_day() {
        $this->data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_of_day";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $this->data);
    }

    public function quiz_edit() {
        $this->data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_edit";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim's method would work just find, but I tend to do it more this way.

```
class Quiz extends CI_Controller {

    public $courses; // can also be set to private

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Mastermodel','',TRUE);
        $this->courses = $this->Mastermodel->get_courses();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['courses'] = $this->courses;
        $data['view_file'] = "content/quiz/quiz_list";
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard/layout', $data);
    }
```